# How to read values with different datatype in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a query (simple `SELECT` statement) which returns Id and Name where `Id is int` and `Name is string`. The query returns result in SSMS. I am trying to get that record using EF in my MVC application. I can get that value if I create custom class but not of I use `dictionary`. Second option doesn't throw any error but it comes with zero record.

How can I read the value without creating custom class?

**C# Logic:**

```
// Option-1 = Works
var sql = @"SELECT UnitNumber, 
                   UnitName
            FROM dbo.MyTable 
            WHERE Id = @p0
            AND ScriptId = @p1";

var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(sql, callCenterId, id);

public class MyClass
{
    public int UnitNumber { get; set; }
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
}


// Option-2 = Doesn't Work
var sql = @"SELECT UnitNumber, 
                   UnitName
            FROM dbo.MyTable 
            WHERE Id = @p0
            AND ScriptId = @p1";

var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Dictionary<int, string>>(sql, callCenterId, id);
```

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT UnitNumber, 
       UnitName
FROM dbo.MyTable 
WHERE Id = 1
AND ScriptId = 10
```

**SQL Output:**

```
UnitNumber  UnitName
----------- -----------
9           Universal
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect option #2 to work. The query is not returning columns that can be converted to a dictionary. Just use a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to project your resultset into a dictionary, like this :

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(sql, callCenterId, id)
             .ToDictionary(o => o.UnitNumber, o => o.UnitName);
```

or

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(sql, callCenterId, id)
         .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.UnitNumber, x.UnitName))
         .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: This make sense. Thank you.